# AdonisJS : Can't send email via @adonisjs/mail

Tags: email, adonis.js

I use adonis js version 4.1.0 and @adonisjs/mail version ^3.0.10. I'm not sure why. But I'm sure my email and password are correct which previously email can be used normally. Please help me. Thank for your solution. I got this error when I send email `ExceptionHandler Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 136-20020a62188e000000b0050dc7628158sm4991712pfy.50 - gsmtp`

my .env like this

```
MAIL_USERNAME=test@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=testpw
SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
```

and I using

```
const data = `<div>Testing</div>`;
  await Mail.raw(data, (message) => {
    message.to(getEmail.email);
    message
      .from(`${Env.get("MAIL_USERNAME")}`)
      .subject("Test Email Sending");
 });
```

**In my config/mail.js**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a change in Google email policy, you can't send mail using your password.

1. enable 2-step verification [click](https://myaccount.google.com/security?hl=en_GB)
2. create App passwords for your mail [click](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords?)
3. replace your .env MAIL_PASSWORD with generated 16 digit app password.